# How to perform all possible combinations of arithmetic operations on 3 integers?

Tags: python, date-arithmetic, integer-arithmetic

Suppose I have three integers. I want to get a list of all possible values obtained by performing all 16 (4x4 of `*, /, +, -` ) operations among between them.

Like if I have `3 4 1`, we should get values 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12,
13, 15 and 16. That is,

`res =  num1 (op1) num2 (op2) num3` where operators are:

`["**", "*/", "*+", "*-", "/*", "//", "/+", "/-", "+*", "+/", "++", "+-", "-*", "-/", "-+", "--"]`

> However, the catch is that division can only be possible if **`x%y==0`** i.e. divisor is factor of dividend.

So, far I've been able to brute force every operation but am missing some answers. I also defined a custom divide operation to take **the catch into account**.

**I'm required to return a list containing unique values that are all positive.**

---

My current code is a mess but here it is for the sake of it. This is missing out some values too.

```py
def div(x, y):
    if x!=0 and y!=0:
        if x%y==0:return x/y
        else:return None


ops_lis = ["**", "*/", "*+", "*-", "/*", "//", "/+", "/-", "+*", "+/", "++", "+-", "-*", "-/", "-+", "--"]

d1, d2, d3 = map(int, input().split())
cal_lis, res_lis = [], []
for op in ops_lis:
    if op[0] == "*" and op[1] == "*":cal_lis.append(d1*d2*d3)
    if op[0] == "*" and op[1] == "/":
        if div(d1*d2, d3) != None:cal_lis.append(div(d1*d2, d3))
        cal_lis.append(div(d1*d2, d3))
    if op[0] == "*" and op[1] == "+":
        cal_lis.append(d1*(d2+d3))
        cal_lis.append((d1*d2)+d3)
    if op[0] == "*" and op[1] == "-":
        cal_lis.append(d1*d2-d3)
        cal_lis.append(d1*(d2-d3))
        cal_lis.append((d1*d3)-d2)
    if op[0] == "/" and op[1] == "*":cal_lis.append(div(d1, d2*d3))
    if op[0] == "/" and op[1] == "/":
        if div(d1, d2) == None or div(d2, d3) == None:
            cal_lis.append(None)
        else:
            cal_lis.append(div(div(d1, d2), d3))
    if op[0] == "/" and op[1] == "+":
        if div(d1, d2) == None:
            cal_lis.append(None)
        else:
            cal_lis.append(div(d1, d2)+d3)
    if op[0] == "/" and op[1] == "-":
        if div(d1, d2) == None:
            cal_lis.append(None)
        else:
            cal_lis.append(div(d1, d2)-d3)

    if op[0] == "+" and op[1] == "*":
        cal_lis.append(d1+d2*d3)
        cal_lis.append((d1+d2)*d3)
        cal_lis.append((d1+d3)*d2)
    if op[0] == "+" and op[1] == "/":
        if div(d2, d3) == None:
            cal_lis.append(None)
        else:
            cal_lis.append(d1+div(d2, d3))
    if op[0] == "+" and op[1] == "+":cal_lis.append(d1+d2+d3)
    if op[0] == "+" and op[1] == "-":cal_lis.append(d1+d2-d3)

    if op[0] == "-" and op[1] == "*":
        cal_lis.append(d1-d2*d3)
        cal_lis.append((d1-d2)*d3)
        cal_lis.append((d1-d3)*d2)
    if op[0] == "-" and op[1] == "/":
        if div(d2, d3) == None:cal_lis.append(None)
        else: cal_lis.append(d1-div(d2, d3))
        if div(d1-d2, d3) == None:cal_lis.append(None)    
        else: cal_lis.append(div(d1-d2, d3))
    if op[0] == "-" and op[1] == "+":cal_lis.append(d1-d2+d3)
    if op[0] == "-" and op[1] == "-":cal_lis.append(d1-d2-d3)

# print(cal_lis)
cal_lis = [int(cal) for cal in cal_lis if cal!=None]
for res in cal_lis:
    if (res > 0 and res not in res_lis):
        res_lis.append(int(res))
for a in sorted(res_lis):
    print(a, end=" ")
print()
```

Is there an efficient way to perform this task (using trees maybe ?) given that the division condition is also true ?

Any help would be appreciated...

---

EDIT: Added Constraints

The calculation must conform to the following format:
number = dice1 op1 dice2 op2 dice3

where:

- op1 and op2 can be +, -, * or /. E.g. op1 = + and op2 = /
- dice1, dice2 and dice3 can be any combination of the numbers rolled at the current round. The value of a die can be used once in the calculation.
- For the division, the divisor must be a factor of the dividend
- Parentheses can be added to override the precedence of operators op1
  and op2. i.e. (dice1 op1 dice2) op2 dice3 or dice1 op1 (dice2 op2 dice3)

Comment: Your requirements don't seem to make sense.  How are you supposed to get a positive value for 3-4*1?  Why have you provided a listing of all the operators when you're only going to use four of them?  And when you "can't divide" something what are you supposed to do?

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. So here's how it's supposed to work. I have to use the operators in all those 16 possibilities not just 4 of them. When I can't divide by something, the result is a None object and I continue adding to result either None or the division result. All the None's are later removed and we take only the positive values (>0).

Comment: if you have list `3 4 1`, what operations will give you 1, 15 or 16 ??

Comment: @lenik 15 is given by 3*(4+1), 16 by 3+1*4 (?) and 1 by (3+1)/4. I had the possible values for `3 4 1` as those numbers in the problem statement and this is how I rendered it in code. It feels odd to me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all possible results, you will need to include grouping of operations in you combinations.  I would suggest a recursive function for this:

```
def calcAll(*values,seen=None):
    seen = seen or set()
    if len(values) == 2:
        a,b  = values
        a,sa = (a[0],f"({a[1]})") if isinstance(a,tuple) else (a,str(a))
        b,sb = (b[0],f"({b[1]})") if isinstance(b,tuple) else (b,str(b))
        if a>b : a,sa, b,sb = b,sb, a,sa
        if (a,b) in seen or seen.add((a,b)) :return                
        yield a+b, f"{sa}+{sb}"
        yield a*b, f"{sa}*{sb}"
        yield a-b, f"{sa}-{sb}"
        yield b-a, f"{sb}-{sa}"
        if b != 0 and a%b==0: yield a//b, f"{sa}/{sb}"
        if a != 0 and b%a==0: yield b//a, f"{sb}/{sa}"
        return
    pairs = ((i,j) for i in range(len(values)-1) for j in range(i+1,len(values)))
    for i,j in pairs:
        rest = [*values]
        a,b  = rest.pop(j),rest.pop(i)
        for paired in calcAll(a,b,seen=seen):            
            for result in calcAll(paired,*rest):
               if result in seen or seen.add(result): continue
               yield result
```

output:

```
# distinct positive solutions sorted by result
for r,sr in sorted(calcAll(3,4,1)):
    if r>0: print(sr,"=",r)

(1*4)-3 = 1
4-(3/1) = 1
(4/1)-3 = 1
(4-3)*1 = 1
4/(1+3) = 1
4-(1*3) = 1
(4-3)/1 = 1
1/(4-3) = 1
3/(4-1) = 1
(1+3)/4 = 1
(4-1)/3 = 1
1-(3-4) = 2
4-(3-1) = 2
(1+4)-3 = 2
(1-3)+4 = 2
(4-3)+1 = 2
4/(3-1) = 2
(4-1)+3 = 6
(3-1)+4 = 6
3-(1-4) = 6
4-(1-3) = 6
(4+3)-1 = 6
(1*4)+3 = 7
(3/1)+4 = 7
(4/1)+3 = 7
(1*3)+4 = 7
(4+3)/1 = 7
(4+3)*1 = 7
(1+4)+3 = 8
(1+3)+4 = 8
(3-1)*4 = 8
(4+3)+1 = 8
(4-1)*3 = 9
(4*3)-1 = 11
(1*4)*3 = 12
(4*3)*1 = 12
(4*3)/1 = 12
(1*3)*4 = 12
(3/1)*4 = 12
(4/1)*3 = 12
(4*3)+1 = 13
(1+4)*3 = 15
(1+3)*4 = 16
```

If you only want the distinct positive results:

```
print( set(r for r,_ in calcAll(3,4,1) if r>0) )
{1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16}
```

The function also works for larger lists of numbers:

```
# one solution for each positive result of operations between 4 numbers
for r,sr in sorted(dict(calcAll(1,2,3,4)).items()):
    if r>0: print(sr,"=",r)
(2/1)+(3-4) = 1
(2-1)-(3-4) = 2
(2/1)-(3-4) = 3
(4*3)/(2+1) = 4
((4*3)/2)-1 = 5
(4*3)/(2/1) = 6
((4*3)/2)+1 = 7
(4+3)-(1-2) = 8
(4*3)-(2+1) = 9
(4*3)-(2/1) = 10
(1-2)+(4*3) = 11
(4*3)/(2-1) = 12
(4*3)-(1-2) = 13
(2/1)+(4*3) = 14
(2+1)+(4*3) = 15
(1+(4+3))*2 = 16
(3*(4+2))-1 = 17
(3/1)*(4+2) = 18
(3*(4+2))+1 = 19
((3*2)-1)*4 = 20
(2+1)*(4+3) = 21
((4*3)-1)*2 = 22
(2*(4*3))-1 = 23
(2/1)*(4*3) = 24
(2*(4*3))+1 = 25
(1+(4*3))*2 = 26
(1+(4*2))*3 = 27
(1+(3*2))*4 = 28
(4+1)*(3*2) = 30
(3+1)*(4*2) = 32
(2+1)*(4*3) = 36
```

And also for duplicate numbers:

```
for r,sr in sorted(dict(calcAll(3,3,3)).items()):
    if r>0: print(sr,"=",r)

3-(3/3) = 2
3/(3/3) = 3
(3/3)+3 = 4
(3*3)-3 = 6
(3+3)+3 = 9
(3*3)+3 = 12
(3+3)*3 = 18
(3*3)*3 = 27
```

Comment: This is a wonderful solution sir ! However, I was able to get it working through extensive itertools usage. This is an excellent example of using recursion and is more pythonic too !

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses `itertools` to generate each combination of two operators and Python's `eval` to evaluate the string.

```
from itertools import product
ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
nums = [3, 4, 0]

combos = product(ops, repeat=2)
for expr in combos:
        eval_me = f'{nums[0]} {expr[0]} {nums[1]} {expr[1]} {nums[2]}'
        try:
            result = eval(eval_me)
            print (f'{eval_me} = {result}')
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print (f'expression "{eval_me}" caused an exception: {e}')
```

With 4 operators, we have 4 * 4 = 16 results.

Here are the results:

```
3 + 4 + 0 = 7
3 + 4 - 0 = 7
3 + 4 * 0 = 3
expression "3 + 4 / 0" caused an exception: division by zero
3 - 4 + 0 = -1
3 - 4 - 0 = -1
3 - 4 * 0 = 3
expression "3 - 4 / 0" caused an exception: division by zero
3 * 4 + 0 = 12
3 * 4 - 0 = 12
3 * 4 * 0 = 0
expression "3 * 4 / 0" caused an exception: division by zero
3 / 4 + 0 = 0.75
3 / 4 - 0 = 0.75
3 / 4 * 0 = 0.0
expression "3 / 4 / 0" caused an exception: float division by zero
```

Comment: It's good. But I was looking for operations on 3 numbers together not in bunches of 2 sir.

Comment: 4 * 4 is not 12

Comment: edited. That was left over from the first solution.

Comment: Since the answer is meeting the constraints of the original question, I'd suggest you accept this answer and post a new question. If this is an assignment, perhaps you should take the given solution and work the rest of it yourself.

Comment: @rajah9 yes sir this was an assignment, I was able to extend the constraints to my desire with the guidance from your solution. Now it is working when I permuted over the numbers as well. Thank You Very Much !

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
nums = [34, 12, 6]

itertools.combinations_with_replacement(ops_lis, len(nums) - 1)
```

You can use the following to get all permutations for the operands:

```
itertools.permutations(nums)
```

You can then build all possible expressions using three nested loops and use eval() to evaluate the expressions.

to get all combinations of operators.

Comment: Thank you for this @Tarik. However, I'm not able to understand how to utilize 3 loops that you mentioned to evaluate all expressions. Sorry for asking (I'm a high-school student)  but can you please give me another hint ?
Thanks !

Comment: One loop to go through all permutations of operands, one loop to go through all combinations of operators, and one loop to build the expression and evaluate it. You may alternatively opt to use itertools to get the Cartesian product, use a map function and filter.

Answer (score 0):

here is my quick solution.
I am making use of np.nan which  after any computation will stay as np.nan so we can identify combinations which does not satisfy condition.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

def plus(a, b):
    return a + b

def minus(a, b):
    return a - b

def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

def div(a, b):
    if b!=0:
        if a%b==0:
            return a//b
    return np.nan


def combinations(nums, funcs):
    t = []
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        t.append(nums)
        t.append(funcs)
    t.append(nums)
    return list(itertools.product(*t))

def solve(instance):
    instance = list(instance)
    for i in range(len(instance)//2):
        b = instance.pop()
        func = instance.pop()
        a = instance.pop()
        instance.append(func(a, b))
    return instance[0]

def main():
    a = [1, 3 ,4]
    func = [plus, minus, mult, div]
    combs = combinations(a, func)
    solutions = [solve(i) for i in combs]
    for i, j in zip(combs, solutions):
        print(i, j)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It is solving operations from right to left but you can change to solve function as you wish.

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted. It seems correct to me. +1 from me :-)