# How to perform all possible combinations of arithmetic operations?

Tags: r

I am looking for some help with how to evaluate permutations of arithmetic operations in R.

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558074/how-to-perform-all-possible-combinations-of-arithmetic-operations-on-3-integers).

Using the gtools package I can easily generate permutations of arithmetic operators

```
library(gtools)
#permutations of operations
permutations(2, 3, c("*", "/"), repeats.allowed = TRUE)
```

Which gives the following output

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "*"  "*"  "*"
[2,] "*"  "*"  "/" 
[3,] "*"  "/"  "*" 
[4,] "*"  "/"  "/" 
[5,] "/"  "*"  "*"
[6,] "/"  "*"  "/" 
[7,] "/"  "/"  "*" 
[8,] "/"  "/"  "/"
```

My question is how to take these permutations and use them elsewhere.

I've had some luck using:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(x)))
```

But I think this is the wrong way to approach it.

Example of usage:

Example dataframe with integers:

```
testmatrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)) #dataframe with 4 columns with integers up to 16
```

dataframe:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
 1 5 9 13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
4 8 12 16
```

Create calculated column based on arithmetic permutation from above

first permutation is `"*"`,`"*"`,`"*"`

calculated with dplyr:

```
testmatrix %>% mutate(.[[1]]*.[[2]]*.[[3]]*.[[4]])
```

So result of permutation:

`...
   V1 V2 V3 V4 Result of permutation V1*V2*V3*V4
     1 5 9 13 585
    2 6 10 14 1680
    3 7 11 15 3465
    4 8 12 16 6144
...`

Then I want to do this for all permutations of the arithmetic operations without having to manually type it out.

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Please show an example of how you want to use it.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah I've added an example of how it is to be used.

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what you want, but if I'm understanding correctly try creating a named list mapping operator string to operator function. That plus a reduce call should make this pretty easy

Comment: So do you have only 8 rows in the `df` ? Please make this question specific show actual values that you have in `df` and show expected output for it.

Comment: Apologies for it being unclear. I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(1:16,4,4)
```

Get `ops` with base-R functions:

```
ops <- do.call(expand.grid,
               c(list(replicate(3,c("*","/"),simplify=FALSE)),
                 list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
```

Use `get()` instead of `eval()` - a little safer/more principled.  This is a little bit clunky, might be able to get a better/more general solution using `Reduce()`:

```
f <- function(x,ops) {
    r1 <- get(ops[[1]])(x[1],x[2])
    r2 <- get(ops[[2]])(r1,x[3])
    r3 <- get(ops[[3]])(r2,x[4])
    return(r3)
}
```

For each set of operators, `apply()` over the rows of the matrix ...

```
res <- vector("list",nrow(ops))
for (i in seq(nrow(ops))) {
    res[[i]] <- apply(m,1,f,ops=ops[i,])
}
res
```

---

I don't see a way to use `Reduce()` but here's a slightly more general version of `f()`:

```
f <- function(x,ops) {
    r <- get(ops[[1]])(x[1],x[2])
    for (j in 2:length(ops)) {
        r <- get(ops[[j]])(r,x[j+1])
    }
    return(r)
}
```